# Plot max of every column of dataframe across hours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a monthly time series data (5min) in which each day is a column and each 5min is a row so the shape is (288,30). I would like to plot all the data as thin lines with low alpha. Also, on the same graph I would like to plot the maximum values on their respective time ID as thick dots, to illustrate where they occur.

I have tried the code below but cannot link the timeindex axis with those ID of the maximum values.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(8640, 1)),index=pd.date_range(start="20180301", freq='5T',periods=8640),columns=['A'])

df_all_days=df.groupby(df.index.time).aggregate(lambda x:list(x))
df_all_days_exp=df_all_days.apply(pd.Series)

df_all_days_exp_Max=df_all_days_exp.max(axis=0)
df_all_days_exp_MaxID=df_all_days_exp.idxmax(axis=0)
df_all_days_exp_Max_ID=pd.DataFrame([df_all_days_exp_Max,df_all_days_exp_MaxID]).T

plt.figure()
plt.plot(df_all_days_exp,linewidth=0.3,alpha=0.4)
plt.plot(df_all_days_exp_Max_ID,'.k',linewidth=1.5)
```

Answer (score -1):

IIUC, you can try:

```
hour_df = df.resample('H').max()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

df.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.1)

ax2 = ax.twiny()
ax2.scatter(range(len(hour_df)), hour_df, c='r')
ax2.set_xticks([])

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]